# Contact form url issue

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

Facing issues with contact form 7. I have posted this issue days before but no one was responding. Same time I was also searching for solutions and I didn't find any good one. The problem is the URL is changing when we click on submit after filling all the fields.

Say for example: 
If this is the link "https://netbramhadev.wpengine.com" this link will change to this "https://netbramhadev.wpengine.com/#wpcf7-f42-o2" after submit.

How can we remove that? Do I need to change anything in wordpress or add extra script for that? Share your knowledge please. Thanks :)

Comment: It would seem that you probably have some other Ajax function that is conflicting with the default behavior of CF7

Comment: There is JS error in your site. You can check it in console. Most probably this is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Hi try with this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/wpcf7-redirect/

This plugin redirects after submit  form

Change it to redirect you back on your contact form.

Answer (score 0):

At first, what can you do is just check whether JS for contact form 7 is loaded or not.
Go to "Plugin Editor" -> Select "Contact Form 7" -> find the below code in "wp-contact-form-7.php":-

```
if ( ! defined( 'WPCF7_LOAD_JS' ) ) {
define( 'WPCF7_LOAD_JS', true );
}
```

If you find the above same line then, the JS file of your active theme or any other active plugin is conflicting with your contact form 7 JS file. Try deactivate a plugin at a time and check if the issue resolves. And then check your theme.

I think it's happening because you have JS file for the contact form in your theme. Just check your "contact.js" and "common.js" files in your theme script-folder.